# OleDBConnection Parameter How to Use

Tags: c#

I'm having a tough time getting parameters working with a OleDBConnection. It should select the correct table based on a query string.

```
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;            
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@table", table));
    command.CommandText = "SELECT [title] from @table ORDER BY [title] ASC";              
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: You cannot parametrize the tablename. You could store all allowed table-names in the string-collection, then you can use: `if(allowedTables.Contains(table)){ command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT [title] from {0} ORDER BY [title] ASC", table); ... }`

Comment: parameters are typically used for parameterizing join/where criteria and should ALWAYS be parameterized to prevent SQL-Injection.